# Why ImageView of screen is not drawn

Tags: android, animation, imageview, off-screen

I need to create a bounce animation on a layout that contains a `RecyclerView` and an `ImageView`. To simplify the explanation here is an illustration of my current layout:

[image]

The `RecyclerView` (**Red**) take all screen size, and under it I position an `ImageView` (**Green**) that is not seen at the beginning. those two view are contained by a `LinearLayout` (**Blue**) with a vertical orientations.

What I want to do is to move the `LinearLayout` 50dp up and then drop it back with the bounce animation so that the image view will be visible only during this animation.

The problem is that when I raise the `LinearLayout` with this code:

```
mLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mLayout.animate().y(-500f);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

The ImageView is not shown, more over when I use the DDMS and get a snapshot of the XML layout after the move animation it looks like the image is not even part of the layout.

**UPDATE:** The xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.MyTopics.Theme"
            tools:mContext=".ui.fragments.MyTopicsFragment">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_timeline_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_container">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.lsjwzh.widget.recyclerviewpager.RecyclerViewPager
            android:id="@+id/vertical_recycler_view"
            style="@style/NoOverScrollStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:rvp_singlePageFling="true"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/first_time_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_below="@+id/swipe_refresh"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:src="@drawable/drawable_image_tutorial_background"/>

</LinearLayout>


<com.shellanoo.newsbot.ui.views.GeneralErrorView
    android:id="@+id/no_data_errors_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:gev_no_data_view_layout="@layout/view_no_data_timeline"/>

<com.shellanoo.newsbot.ui.views.ProgressWheel
    android:id="@+id/loading_pb"
    style="@style/AppTheme.ProgressBar.Large"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_topics_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/profile_main"
    tools:visibility="visible"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/add_topics_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="24dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/plus_main"
    tools:visibility="visible"/>

<com.shellanoo.newsbot.ui.views.NewStoriesIndicatorView
    android:id="@+id/new_items_tip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="8dp"
    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
    tools:text="5 new items"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Does someone know why, and how this can be fixed?

Comment: share your xml code may be you have provided match_parent attribute in recyclerview, you must restrict the height of recylcerview, use a relativelayout/linearlayout as parent

Comment: You should use RelativeLayout as a parent, is lighter and it might help with the overlapping issue you have, can you post the xml layout please?

Comment: @SaravInfern layout added.

Comment: you have added match parent attribute in your swiperefresh layout change it

Comment: changing swiperefreshlayout height to wrap_content does not change the behavior. The ImageView is still not visible.

Comment: put your animation layout inside scroll view

Comment: @AkshayBhat, tried that... but the scrollview messes up all my layout.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
 <RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/layout"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="200dp">


    <com.lsjwzh.widget.recyclerviewpager.RecyclerViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vertical_recycler_view"
        style="@style/NoOverScrollStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:rvp_singlePageFling="true"
        android:minHeight="200dp"/>   


    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/first_time_image"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:scaleType="centerCrop"
         android:layout_below="@+id/swipe_refresh"
         android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
         android:src="@drawable/drawable_image_tutorial_background"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Tried using RelativeLayout with SwipeRefreshLayout with wrap_content height but the result is the same. the image is not displayed.